# How to select records not selected by inner select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select pid from table where pid is not (select top 10 pid from table1)
```

What is the correct syntax for the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select pid from table where pid not in (select top 10 pid from table1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`not in`, instead of `is not`